# Nextjs 14 app router complain I am breaking hooks rule while I am not

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13

Warning: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:

1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
   See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
   ⨯ TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useState')
   at SelectedItemsUser (./components/Header/SelectedItemUser.jsx:24:86)

```
'use client';
import { FaShoppingCart } from 'react-icons/fa';
import { useState } from 'react';
import { FaChevronDown, FaChevronUp } from 'react-icons/fa';
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import SkinCard from '@components/Skins/SkinCard';
import { SUPPORTED_CURRENCIES, paths } from '@app/paths';
import { usePathname } from 'next/navigation';
const SelectedItemsUser = (props) => {
    const {left,authenticated} = props;
    const [collapsed, setCollapsed] = useState(false);
    const {t} = useTranslation('trade');
    const selectedItems = useSelector(state => state.userInventory);
    const path = usePathname();
    const getItemPrice = (item) => {
        switch(path){
        case paths.BUY:
            return item.buyPrice;
        case paths.SELL:
            return item.price;
        case paths.TRADE:
            return item.tradePrice;
        default:
            return item.price;
        }
    };
    
    return (
        <div className={`w-full flex flex-col gap-1 rounded-6 overflow-hidden transition-all duration-200 select-none bg-bg-16 ${collapsed ? 'hover:bg-bg-29' : ''}`}>
            <div className={`w-full h-12 flex ${left ? 'flex-row-reverse' : 'flex-row'} items-center justify-between cursor-pointer ${collapsed ? 'bg-inherit' : 'transition-all duration-200 bg-bg-16 hover:bg-bg-29'} px-6 py-2`} onClick={() => setCollapsed(prev => !prev)}>
                <div className={`h-full flex ${left ? 'flex-row-reverse' : 'flex-row'} gap-2 items-center h-12 text-main`}>
                    <FaShoppingCart className="text-current text-12 xl:text-14" color="#FF4B4B"/>
                    
                    <p className="text-12 text-main font-medium flex flex-row items-center">
                        <span>{SUPPORTED_CURRENCIES[props.activeCurrency]?.symbol || '$'}{selectedItems.reduce((acc, item) => acc + (getItemPrice(item) / 100), 0).toFixed(2)}</span>
                    </p>
                    
                    {selectedItems && selectedItems.length >0 && (
                        <p className="text-10 bg-red text-main font-medium flex flex-row items-center py-0 px-1.5 rounded-full">{selectedItems.length}</p>
                    )}
                </div>
                <div className={`center gap-1.5 select-none text-main flex ${left ? 'flex-row' : 'flex-row-reverse'}`}>
                    {collapsed
                        ? (<FaChevronDown className={`text-current text-10 xl:text-12 ${left ? 'mr-2' : 'ml-2'}`} />)
                        : (<FaChevronUp className={`text-current text-10 xl:text-12 ${left ? 'mr-2' : 'ml-2'}`} />)
                    }
                    <p className="text-12 text-main font-medium capitalize">{t('trade_title')} {left ? t('trade_title_1') : t('trade_title_2')}</p>
                    <svg width="13" height="9" viewBox="0 0 13 9" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                        <path d="M10.2055 5.67345H5.78483C5.45973 5.67345 5.19629 5.9369 5.19629 6.26199C5.19629 6.58696 5.45974 6.85053 5.78483 6.85053H10.3847L9.28262 8.00511C9.05819 8.24035 9.06689 8.6129 9.30213 8.83721C9.53725 9.06164 9.90982 9.05294 10.1342 8.81782L12.0959 6.76217C12.313 6.53476 12.313 6.17688 12.0959 5.94945L10.1342 3.89379C9.9098 3.65868 9.53723 3.64998 9.30213 3.87441C9.06689 4.09884 9.05819 4.47128 9.28262 4.7065L10.2055 5.67345Z" fill="#FF4B4B" />
                        <path d="M2.05325 1.96182H6.47397C6.79894 1.96182 7.06251 2.22527 7.06251 2.55036C7.06251 2.87545 6.79893 3.1389 6.47397 3.1389H1.87414L2.97617 4.29361C3.20048 4.52873 3.19178 4.9013 2.95666 5.12571C2.72155 5.35011 2.34897 5.34131 2.12457 5.1062L0.16273 3.05054C-0.0542433 2.82313 -0.0542433 2.46535 0.16273 2.23795L2.12457 0.182294C2.349 -0.0529462 2.72157 -0.0616471 2.95666 0.162784C3.19178 0.387214 3.20048 0.759785 2.97617 0.994882L2.05325 1.96182Z" fill="#FF4B4B" fillOpacity="0.25" />
                    </svg>
                </div>
            </div>
```

I am using redux

I have tried to move the hooks around, and also import pathname as prop which didnt help either. Dont know how to fix this. I am using nextjs 14 app router and is fairly new to it.

Answer (score 0):

After a first look, your usage of the hooks seems good. So I would say it is not 2.

Remain 1. and 3.

1. Have you checked which version of `react` and `react-dom` you are using. Following the documentation next.js has strong requirements: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/react-version
2. Do you use 2 versions of React in your project?

Comment: I only see one react in package.json, and the "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0" is what I have used

Comment: You can have different versions due to the dependencies of your other packages. You can checkout package-lock.json and confirm the details.